# Does one need to pin array parameters into COM RCWs in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I'm calling the [`IDiaSourceFile::get_checksum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44y24e8y.aspx) member function, which has the following auto-generated .NET signature:

```
void get_checksum(uint cbData, out uint pcbData, byte[] pbData);
```

Note that the parameter `pbData` is an out parameter. Do I need to worry about pinning the array passed in here when someone calls `get_checksum`?

(Background:

I inherited some code that looks like this:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* p = scratch_hash)
    {
        sourceFile.get_checksum(c, out c, scratch_hash);
    }
}
```

which pins `scratch_hash` as `p` and then never actually uses `p`. I've not seen anything like this before and given the state of the surrounding code I suspect the pin is completely unnecessary here

)

Comment: That's what everybody *likes* the method to be marshaled to.  But that's not what happens, a byte* is not the same as a byte[].  C arrays are far too broken to allow that to happen, empowering a billion bugs and buffer overflow attacks.  Only a SAFEARRAY marshals to byte[].

Comment: Oh, this is COM interop. So you can't even change the signature, can you? Are you using `tlbimp` to create a wrapper library, or are you using your own in C++/CLI? As far as I know `tlbimp` doesn't allow you to pass variable-length arrays (you'd have to edit the IL manually to use that functionality), so I've got to ask - does this code actually work?

Comment: @Hans: I don't understand what you mean. That's the signature I have.

Comment: @Luaan: It appears to, yes.

Comment: You don't have that signature, you can't pass byte* when the compiler expects byte[].  That only works in C, the C# compiler won't permit it.  Nor is the way that COM interop works.  Just try to write code like that yourself to see that, it will always die on CS1503.

Comment: @Hans: I just found out that someone changed the IL for the generated DLL for this function to be `[out] uint8[]  marshal([256]) pbData` :/ That's very sad :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current definition:

```
void get_checksum(uint cbData, out uint pcbData, byte[] pbData);
```

You don't need to pin `pbData`. However, you'd need to pre-allocate an array for the returned the data, but you don't know the size in advance. The method will fail if the array size you pass via `cbData` is not large enough, and your current method signature doesn't allow to find out the buffer size.

The [original C++ declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44y24e8y.aspx) does allow that:

```
HRESULT get_checksum ( 
   DWORD  cbData,
   DWORD* pcbData,
   BYTE   data[]
);
```

> data [in, out] A buffer that is filled with the checksum bytes. If
>   this parameter is NULL, then pcbData returns the number of bytes
>   required.

So, a more efficient approach might be to declare and use it like this:

```
void get_checksum(
    uint cbData, 
    out uint pcbData, 
    IntPtr data);
```

```
// get size
uint size;
obj.get_checksum(0, out size, IntPtr.Zero);

// get data
var buff = new byte[size];
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* p = buff)
    {
        uint cbData;
        obj.get_checksum(size, out cbData, (IntPtr)p);
        if (size != cbData)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("cbData");
    }
}
```

If you don't want (or can't) use `unsafe` code, here's an alternative:

```
// get size
uint size;
obj.get_checksum(0, out size, IntPtr.Zero);

// get the data
byte[] buff;
var p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)size);
try
{
    uint cbData;
    obj.get_checksum(size, out cbData, p);
    if (size < cbData)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("cbData");
    buff = new byte[cbData];
    Marshal.Copy(p, buff, 0, (int)cbData);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
}
```

Comment: I can't just pass in null for `byte[]`? `int size; get_checksum(0, out size, null); byte[] result = new byte[size]; get_checksum(size, out size, result); return result;`

Comment: @BillyONeal, you probably can, if you use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pbData` signature. Try that and post your own answer. In either case, you don't need to pin it, unless you pass it to COM as `IntPtr`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to do it in this case - and you can't, even.

However, you might want to change that signature if you run into performance issues, because the marshaller does a lot of work to pass the byte array to the native method - it has to allocate new memory, copy the managed byte array to that, and then deallocate the memory again.

This means that the code you posted is complete nonsense, because while it does fix the `scratch_hash` array, it doesn't use that fixed pointer anyway.

If you're only calling the method once in a while and the byte array is relatively small, this can be safely ignored. However, if you do find that this causes unnecessary strain on your application, fixing could help - but you'd have to change the signature:

```
unsafe void get_checksum(uint cbData, out uint pcbData, byte *pbData);
```

Then you can use this:

```
fixed (byte *p = &scratch_hash[0])
  sourceFile.get_checksum(c, out c, p);
```

All this said, note that fixing a managed object might cause issues of its own (for example, it pretty much kills any chance of heap compaction if your object is on top of the heap). Fixing should be done sparingly, and only for extremely short times - the only other reasonable alternative is to allocate the objects early, and keeping them together (for example, when using asynchronous I/O, you need a fixed reference, usually for as long as the application runs - so just allocate the buffers as early as possible, and you'll be mostly fine).

Also, I'm still finding that signature a bit wild. Could you share the header file's definition of the signature?

Comment: `HRESULT get_checksum(DWORD cbData, DWORD* pcbData, BYTE* data)` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44y24e8y.aspx